# Combination of MAxSMT and user defined cost function in Z3 solver

Tags: z3, smt

I am using the Z3 to optimize a cost function with some soft constraints (with weighted MaxSMT). I was curious about how the MaxSMT and the user-defined cost function interact. Does the solver minimize the MaxSMT cost and the objective function both, is there a priority mechanism? I couldn't find any documentation on this, please let me know if I missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@alias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/936310/alias) answered the question from a technical point of view; I interpreted the question from an usability point of view, so I added an answer with a few details.

---

As stated by [@alias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/936310/alias), using `assert-soft` pushes an implicit objective function on the internal objective stack. The **key point** to observe is that this happens at the location in the formula of the first `assert-soft` statement of each group of soft-clauses with a common id `<id>`.

---

The `z3` OMT solver supports 3 multi-objective combination approaches: *Boxed*, *Lexicographic* and *Pareto Optimization*. The last two are quite well known multi-objective optimization approaches. *Boxed* (a.k.a. *Multi-Independent*) optimization is akin to sequentially solving multiple, independent, single-objective problems having the same input formula and different cost function; only that this is done much faster in a single optimization-search swipe.

The optimization combination can be set directly within the formula, at any point in time before the call to `(check-sat)`:

```
(set-option :opt.priority VALUE)
```

where `VALUE` can be either `box`, `lex` or `pareto`.

The multi-objective combination used by `z3` by default is *lexicographic optimization*.

---

The following examples, using *lexicographic optimization*, showcase how the behavior of `z3` changes depending on how `assert-soft` and `minimize`/`maximize` commands are interleaved.

**Example I:** All `assert-soft` statements appear before the `minimize` command. The implicit MaxSMT goal takes precedence over the LIRA goal.

```
(set-option :produce-models true)
(declare-fun x () Int)
(declare-fun y () Int)
(assert (<= 0 x))
(assert (<= 0 y))
(assert-soft (< 2 x) :weight 1 :id pb)
(assert-soft (< 2 y) :weight 1 :id pb)
(minimize (+ x y))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
(get-objectives)
```

results in

```
~$ z3 example_01.smt2
sat
(model 
  (define-fun y () Int
    3)
  (define-fun x () Int
    3)
)
(objectives
 (pb 0)
 ((+ x y) 6)
)
```

**Example II:** All the `assert-soft` statements appear after the `minimize` command. The LIRA goal takes precedence over the implicit MaxSMT goal.

```
(set-option :produce-models true)
(declare-fun x () Int)
(declare-fun y () Int)
(assert (<= 0 x))
(assert (<= 0 y))
(minimize (+ x y))
(assert-soft (< 2 x) :weight 1 :id pb)
(assert-soft (< 2 y) :weight 1 :id pb)
(check-sat)
(get-model)
(get-objectives)
```

results in

```
~$ z3 example_02.smt2
sat
(model 
  (define-fun y () Int
    0)
  (define-fun x () Int
    0)
)
(objectives
 ((+ x y) 0)
 (pb 2)
)
```

**Example III:** Interleaving of `assert-soft` statements with the `minimize` command. The implicit MaxSMT goal takes precedence over the LIRA goal.

```
(set-option :produce-models true)
(declare-fun x () Int)
(declare-fun y () Int)
(assert (<= 0 x))
(assert (<= 0 y))
(assert-soft (< 2 x) :weight 1 :id pb)
(minimize (+ x y))
(assert-soft (< 2 y) :weight 1 :id pb)
(check-sat)
(get-model)
(get-objectives)
```

results in

```
~$ z3 example_03.smt2
sat
(model 
  (define-fun y () Int
    3)
  (define-fun x () Int
    3)
)
(objectives
 (pb 0)
 ((+ x y) 6)
)
```

---

**Note:** other OMT solvers use different multi-objective combination defaults and handle `assert-soft` statements differently, so this is something to keep in mind when trying various solvers.

Comment: Great explanation! This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Hi! I have a follow up question? In my problem, if i have a set of soft constraints (MaxSMT objective) first and then another objective function and the system being optimized lexicographically. Is it safe to assume that the second objective will be optimized over all the possible assignments (solutions) for the optimized MaxSMT objective?

Comment: @KshitijGoyal If the assumption is violated, it is a bug. Hence, yes.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin I'm not sure. Is there any way we can see the possible assignments after the optimization of the first objective?

Comment: @KshitijGoyal you can use the API to incrementally extract all possible assignments one by one, or you can check whether z3 has a command 'check-all-sat' like optimathsat and print all possible models with the same optimal solution for the first objective before you add the second goal. Quite an expensive check and, in the end, not necessary. I'm pretty sure that's the desired semantics.

Answer (score 1):

A soft assertion is essentially treated as a constraint that introduces a penalty to the cost function if not satisfied:

> `(assert-soft F [:weight n | :dweight d ] [:id id ])` - assert soft
>   constraint F, optionally with an integral weight n or a decimal weight
>   d . If no weight is given, the default weight is 1 (1.0). Decimal and
>   integral weights can be mixed freely. Soft constraints can furthermore
>   be tagged with an optional name id. This enables combining multiple
>   different soft objectives. Fig. 1 illustrates a use with soft
>   constraints.

So, in a sense the same MaxSMT engine handles both your general cost function and the soft-constraints in one fell swoop. The above quote and the details are in this paper: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/nbjorner-nuz.pdf

Comment: *AFAIK* `:dweight d` is no longer officially supported by `z3`.  Both rational and integer weights are specified with `:weight c`. I tested this on a recent build of `z3`.